# adding ChrootDirectory to sshd_config to jail a user prevents the user to login

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, chroot

i've created an user on ubuntu 10.04 and wanted to jail the user by disabling ssh shell and allow sftp. when there is no  ChrootDirectory in the sshd_config the user can login just that it can see other sibling folders.

let's say i only want the user to access `/var/www/vhost/shop.mydomain.com` so that's the home folder of my new user is set to that.but the use could browse via filezilla everything under `/var/www/vhost/*`. i followed this [post](http://www.ericstockwell.com/?p=54) and so far that's the only kink. I would be glad if anyone can give me a tip. thanks

Comment: Is the user using an ftp or sftp connection ?

Comment: am(using the user creds to login) using an sftp with filezilla

Answer (score 1):

You need to pay close attention to the notes about permissions on the `ChrootDirectory` section of the man page.

> Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication.  **All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories** that are not writable by any other user or group.  After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.

So `/var`, `/var/www`, `/var/www/vhost`, `/var/www/vhost/shop.mydomain.com` should all look like `drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 date  ...`.

Comment: Indeed it seems i have a problem understanding `After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.` What does that mean? let's say i do sudo chown -R 711 root:root `/var/www` what's next?